# Broken Kernel on 14.04 - can't run any apt-get, dpkg

Tags: 14.04, package-management, kernel, dpkg

I recently tried to upgrade to 15.04. My whole computer is acting extremely strangely from it, I believe the process failed halfway through.

My login screen shows 15.04, but my system info still says 14.04.

I can't run apt-get install for anything, before anything it tries to remove linux-image-extra-3.13.0-74-generic, which it can't seem to do and I have had no luck finding a solution.

I have seen a lot of similar issues crop up on forums, but this one seems to be a little different and I can't seem to get it going. Can anyone provide some insight to this problem?

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-74-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 87 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 152 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 322754 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-74-generic (3.13.0-74.118) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.13.0-74-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-74-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-74-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.13.0-74-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-74-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-74-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-74-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-74-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/casper-memdisk failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-74-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-74-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-74-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue after a lot of terrifying and dangerous tinkering. I'll post what I did, some sort of combination of a bunch of different similar issues I found.

The general solution was to not delete the old kernel at all, and just pretend that its not there.

First:

I edited `/var/lib/dpkg/status` and removed every occurrence of the package `linux-image-extra-3.13.0-74-generic`.

This led to a lot of packages that weren't configured, so I still couldn't' do a whole lot. The solution to this was to purge all of these. It looked like this for me:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.19.0-42-generic linux-image-3.19.0-49-generic linux-image-generic linux-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-42-generic linux-signed-image-3.19.0-42-generic initramfs-tools
```

Then I ran `apt-get update`, followed by `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic`

Then I ran `apt-get install -f` to fix dependencies.

Finally I ran `apt-get autoremove` to get rid of all of the garbage that's been here from whatever I did to my system.

I'm not exactly new to Ubuntu or unix at all, but I tend to stay away from the lower-level nasty bits, mostly use it for software development. If anybody is having similar issues to this, what I have above fixed the problem for me, but I can't exactly recommend it unless you at least sort of know what you're doing. Like I said, i don't *really* know what I'm doing, but I do know that I was playing with fire and the fact that my system is still running is  a miracle.

Answer (score -1):

Any specific reasons why you were trying to upgrade? 
14.04.3 is LTS...in april we will be getting 16.04 LTS anyway. Looking at logs...it's better to resinstall 15.10 all from scratch if you don't have any critical data(if there is some critical data try to login in recovery mode and take a backup of it)
Upgrade to 16.04 LTS is easy from 15.10

Comment: This does not answer the question -1

Comment: @markkirby. this answer infact points to one of the solution logically. You can vote down...but don't you think that if you have better or some other answer you should have provided it for this issue.

Comment: How does this point to a "solution logically" I don't see it and I never said I have a better solution, I said this is not a solution. I have no obligation to provide another answer, all my vote says is I think your answer is rubbish and you have done nothing to convince my otherwise. Explain to me why this is the answer to the question and I will change my vote but just complaining about the vote won't make me change my mind. How does this answer the question???

Comment: @markkirby. Calm down. Neither i am complaining nor I am not asking you to change your vote but don't you think if you are voting down you should provide another answer or better answer.

Comment: No, my vote gives no obligation to provide an answer to the question, did I even say I know the answer? NO, I did not, all the vote says is I don't like this answer, nothing more. You think every time someone downvotes they need to provide an alternative answer? then open a meta post about it, I assure you, no one agrees, 90% of users don't even leave a comment..

Comment: @MarkKirby I don't like the accepted answer either. Indeed I think this whole Q&A should be deleted.